# How to extend line in matlab to the graph limits?

Tags: matlab, line, extension-methods

I have these two points:

```
vx1=-8;
vy1=8;
vz1=7;

vx2=-7;
vy2=9;
vz2=9;
line([vx1 ,vx2],[vy1 ,vy2],[vz1 ,vz2]);
```

Now it will give me a line and I wanna extend it to the graph limits in x,y,and z...
Note that I have many lines in this domain.

Answer (score 1):

You can inspect the limits of the graph by doing

```
hline = line([vx1 ,vx2],[vy1 ,vy2],[vz1 ,vz2]);
hline.Parent.XLim
hline.Parent.YLim
```

etc

but it could be easier to change the graph limits to the maximum/minimum of your line in each dimension. You may use the commands xlim, ylim, zlim

```
xlim([-8 8]);
ylim([8 9]);
zlim([7 9]);
```

If you have several lines, find the min/max of each dimension and use that values for the xlim function.